# Conditional Satement: Does IF Condition have hierarchy?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm studying python and trying to solve a quiz.

In the Gregorian calendar, three conditions are used to identify leap years:

The year can be evenly divided by 4, is a leap year, unless:
The year can be evenly divided by 100, it is NOT a leap year, unless:
The year is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap year.
This means that in the Gregorian calendar, the years 2000 and 2400 are leap years, while 1800, 1900, 2100, 2200, 2300 and 2500 are NOT leap years. Source

**Task**

Given a year, determine whether it is a leap year. If it is a leap year, return the Boolean True, otherwise return False.

Here's my answer but somehow I cant get the output for year 2100 to return false

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    
    if year % 4 == 0:
        return True
    if year % 100 == 0:
        return True
    if year % 400 == 0:
        return leap
    
    #return leap

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

and the perfect answer is this:

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    
    if year % 400 == 0:
        return True
    if year % 100 == 0:
        return leap
    if year % 4 == 0:
        return True
    
    return leap
    
year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

**QUESTION:**
Can someone explain why should the IF statement be arranged on that manner. What's the difference between both answers. I just want to understand why?

Thank you so much for your help.

I tried to analyze the question and make sure the conditions are met but somehow there's something I didn't understand on how to properly use conditional statement. I want to know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Return closes a function. So when you give input as 2100, it should come false because it can be divided by 100 and not by 400.
But your function runs from top to bottom. So when it runs the line:

```
if year % 4 == 0:
```

It appears True and the this line runs:

```
return True
```

If you didn't use "return" here, other lines would run too. But in this case the program ends the function and returns the value - "True". Other lines below "return" doesn't even run.

It's not the hierarchy of "if". It's how a function works.